# Unable to edit author/category for some books in iBook

Tags: macos, books

I know metadata can be edited at the list view, like this:
[image]

The thing is, for some files this works. However, for others, when I quit iBook, open it again, the author and category comes back again. Looks like the metadata never really makes to the server, and when I open iBook again, it syncs with server, and reads back the metadata.

Any one experienced the same thing? And any workaround?

Comment: I have been wondering how to edit Book Authors or Titles -- there is no mention in the HELP files how to do this. But your post has helped - using LIST VIEW ... Many thanks ...hope it sticks!!

Comment: HOW to get to list view in the first place?  Do not see that as an option.